# UL behaves like it does not belong to any class

Tags: html, css

I have a family tree html/css code. In the following example, the code behaves as expected, since I have defined the UL class under the "mother" node to be "normal".

```css
body{
    background-color: FloralWhite;
    font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica", "sans-serif";
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: normal;
}

p{
    margin: 1.5em 0;
}


div.pagecontent { width: 50em; margin:0 auto; font-size: 1.2em;}



/*====================================================================*/

            /* Tree */

.tree ul {
  padding-top: 1.25em; 
  /* 1.25 em = 20 px */
  position: relative;
  padding-inline-start: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree ul li ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;    
    position: relative;
    padding: 1.25em 0 0 0;
    /* 1.25 em = 20 px */
} 

.tree li {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top; /* added this */
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  /*the padding is 20px + border-top = 23px*/
  padding: 1.5625em 0.3125em 0 0.3125em;  
  /* 0.3125em = 5px , 1.5625em = 23px */ 
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/
.tree li::before,
.tree li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 0.3125em solid #ccc;
  width: 50%;
  height: 1.3em;
  /* 1.3125em = 20.8px seems to work well - previously was 19px; */
}

.tree li.dotted::before,
.tree li.dotted::after {
  border-top: 0.1875em dotted #ccc;
  /* 0.1875em = 3px */
}

.tree li::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 0.3125em solid #ccc;
  /* 0.3125em = 5px */
}

.tree li.dotted::after {
   border-left: 0.1875em dotted #ccc;
   /* 0.1875em = 3px */
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/

.tree li:only-child::after,
.tree li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}

/*Remove left connector from first child and right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before,
.tree li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}

/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 0.3125em solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 0.3125em 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0.3125em 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0.3125em 0 0;
}

.tree li.dotted:last-child::before {
  border-right: 0.1875em dotted #456990;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 0; 
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 0.3125em 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.3125em 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.3125em 0 0 0;
}

/* no angle rounding for dotted lines in the exhusband/Woman class: */
.tree li.dotted:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
}


/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/

.tree ul.normal ul.normal::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 1.3125em;
  /* 1.3125em = 21px */
}

.tree ul.normal ul.normal::before {
  border-left: 0.3125em solid #ccc;
}

.tree  ul.dotted ul.dotted::before { 
  border-left: 0.1875em dotted #456990;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
}

.tree li .family {
  position: relative;
}

/* Person */
.person {
  border: 0.1875em solid black;
  padding: 0.09375em;
  /* 0.09375em = 1.5px */
  min-width: 18.75em;
  /* 18.75em = 300px; */
  /* min-height: 6.25em;  to increase the min height of the boxes */
  display: inline-block;
  /* preventing line breaks: */
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.person.female {  
  top: 0px; 
  border-color: #F45B69;
}

.person.male {
  top: 0px;
  border-color: #456990;
}

.person .content {
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica", "sans-serif";
  font-size: 1em;
  align: center; 
  text-align: center;
}


/*-----------------------------*/
```

```html
<html>


<HEAD>
<title> Family tree </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<META http-equiv="content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</HEAD>


<body bgcolor="white" background="" vlink="peru" alink="peru" link="peru">
<p align=center>
<br><br>
<b>
<font size=6> <I> FAMILY TREE </I> </font>
</br>

<div class="tree" align=center>
<ul class="normal">
<li>
    <div class="person child male">
        <div class="content">
            Maurice Dupont </br> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="normal">
        <li>
            <div class="person child male">
                <div class="content">Uncle</br></br></div>
            </div>              
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="person child female">
                <div class="content">Aunt</div>
            </div>              
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="person child female">
                <div class="content">Mother</br></div>
            </div>
            <ul class="normal">
                <li class="dotted">
                    <div class="person child male">
                        <div class="content">Me</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class = "dotted">
                    <div class="person child female">
                        <div class="content">Sister</div>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="normal">
                        <li>
                            <div class="person child male">
                                <div class="content">Me</div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="person child female">
                                <div class="content">Other</div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>   
            </ul>                               
        </li>
    </ul>       
</li>
</ul>
</div>

</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Now, I want the Downward connector of the "Mother" node be a dotted line. So, I define the corresponding UL class as "dotted", but now, the connector disappears, indicating that the UL neither belong to class "normal" nor to class "dotted". But then, to what class does it belong, since there is nothing else in the HTML code? and how to fix that?

html code with the bug:

```css
body{
    background-color: FloralWhite;
    font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica", "sans-serif";
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: normal;
}

p{
    margin: 1.5em 0;
}


div.pagecontent { width: 50em; margin:0 auto; font-size: 1.2em;}



/*====================================================================*/

            /* Tree */

.tree ul {
  padding-top: 1.25em; 
  /* 1.25 em = 20 px */
  position: relative;
  padding-inline-start: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree ul li ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;    
    position: relative;
    padding: 1.25em 0 0 0;
    /* 1.25 em = 20 px */
} 

.tree li {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top; /* added this */
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  /*the padding is 20px + border-top = 23px*/
  padding: 1.5625em 0.3125em 0 0.3125em;  
  /* 0.3125em = 5px , 1.5625em = 23px */ 
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/
.tree li::before,
.tree li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 0.3125em solid #ccc;
  width: 50%;
  height: 1.3em;
  /* 1.3125em = 20.8px seems to work well - previously was 19px; */
}

.tree li.dotted::before,
.tree li.dotted::after {
  border-top: 0.1875em dotted #ccc;
  /* 0.1875em = 3px */
}

.tree li::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 0.3125em solid #ccc;
  /* 0.3125em = 5px */
}

.tree li.dotted::after {
   border-left: 0.1875em dotted #ccc;
   /* 0.1875em = 3px */
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/

.tree li:only-child::after,
.tree li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}

/*Remove left connector from first child and right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before,
.tree li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}

/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 0.3125em solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 0.3125em 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0.3125em 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0.3125em 0 0;
}

.tree li.dotted:last-child::before {
  border-right: 0.1875em dotted #456990;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 0; 
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 0.3125em 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.3125em 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.3125em 0 0 0;
}

/* no angle rounding for dotted lines in the exhusband/Woman class: */
.tree li.dotted:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
}


/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/

.tree ul.normal ul.normal::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 1.3125em;
  /* 1.3125em = 21px */
}

.tree ul.normal ul.normal::before {
  border-left: 0.3125em solid #ccc;
}

.tree  ul.dotted ul.dotted::before { 
  border-left: 0.1875em dotted #456990;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
}

.tree li .family {
  position: relative;
}

/* Person */
.person {
  border: 0.1875em solid black;
  padding: 0.09375em;
  /* 0.09375em = 1.5px */
  min-width: 18.75em;
  /* 18.75em = 300px; */
  /* min-height: 6.25em;  to increase the min height of the boxes */
  display: inline-block;
  /* preventing line breaks: */
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.person.female {  
  top: 0px; 
  border-color: #F45B69;
}

.person.male {
  top: 0px;
  border-color: #456990;
}

.person .content {
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica", "sans-serif";
  font-size: 1em;
  align: center; 
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>


<HEAD>
<title> Family tree </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<META http-equiv="content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</HEAD>


<body bgcolor="white" background="" vlink="peru" alink="peru" link="peru">
<p align=center>
<br><br>
<b>
<font size=6> <I> FAMILY TREE </I> </font>
</br>

<div class="tree" align=center>
<ul class="normal">
<li>
    <div class="person child male">
        <div class="content">
            Maurice Dupont </br> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="normal">
        <li>
            <div class="person child male">
                <div class="content">Uncle</br></br></div>
            </div>              
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="person child female">
                <div class="content">Aunt</div>
            </div>              
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="person child female">
                <div class="content">Mother</br></div>
            </div>
            <ul class="dotted">
                <li class="dotted">
                    <div class="person child male">
                        <div class="content">Me</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class = "dotted">
                    <div class="person child female">
                        <div class="content">Sister</div>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="normal">
                        <li>
                            <div class="person child male">
                                <div class="content">Me</div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="person child female">
                                <div class="content">Other</div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>   
            </ul>                               
        </li>
    </ul>       
</li>
</ul>
</div>

</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi ! Edit your answer and make your code a runnable snippet with the `<>` button. It will show the problem directly to people here and we can even copy the snippet to the answer. It also seems you posted the HTML twice..?

Comment: Your second HTML code still only has a `ul` with a single class: `normal`.

Comment: I made a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/jOXrada) of your code, but I still don't understand your question. If by the "connector" you mean the dotted line between "Mother" and the children, it's there and dotted, in my browser. Tested in FireFox and Chrome on Win11. I also noted that you didn't close the body tag.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware the OP is right, if you replace the first `ul`'s class after Mother to `dotted` in your codepen, the vertical line just under the Mother's rectangle disappears (in the original codepen it appears as a normal line)

Comment: OK, I have edited my question to introduce code snipets and the </body> missing markup. The problem can now be seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem was here:

```
.tree  ul.normal ul.normal::before { ... }

.tree  ul.dotted ul.dotted::before { ... }
```

Because you repeated `ul.normal` and `ul.dotted`, the style was only applied when a normal `ul` was inside a normal `ul`, or when a dotted `ul` was inside a dotted `ul`. You can verify it by opening the developper tools and see what classes apply.

The dotted `ul` after "Mother" is actually inside a normal `ul`, so neither of the 2 styles applied. There was no `border-left` on it and it disappeared.

I replaced it by this and it seems to work fine:

```
.tree  ul.normal::before { ... }

.tree  ul.dotted::before { ... }
```

```css
body{
   background-color: FloralWhite;
   font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica", "sans-serif";
   font-size: 100%;
   font-weight: normal;
}

p{
   margin: 1.5em 0;
}


div.pagecontent { width: 50em; margin:0 auto; font-size: 1.2em;}



/*====================================================================*/

           /* Tree */

.tree ul {
 padding-top: 1.25em; 
 /* 1.25 em = 20 px */
 position: relative;
 padding-inline-start: 0;
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree ul li ul {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;    
   position: relative;
   padding: 1.25em 0 0 0;
   /* 1.25 em = 20 px */
} 

.tree li {
 display: table-cell;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: top; /* added this */
 list-style-type: none;
 position: relative;
 /*the padding is 20px + border-top = 23px*/
 padding: 1.5625em 0.3125em 0 0.3125em;  
 /* 0.3125em = 5px , 1.5625em = 23px */ 
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/
.tree li::before,
.tree li::after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 50%;
 border-top: 0.3125em solid #ccc;
 width: 50%;
 height: 1.3em;
 /* 1.3125em = 20.8px seems to work well - previously was 19px; */
}

.tree li.dotted::before,
.tree li.dotted::after {
 border-top: 0.1875em dotted #ccc;
 /* 0.1875em = 3px */
}

.tree li::after {
 right: auto;
 left: 50%;
 border-left: 0.3125em solid #ccc;
 /* 0.3125em = 5px */
}

.tree li.dotted::after {
  border-left: 0.1875em dotted #ccc;
  /* 0.1875em = 3px */
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/

.tree li:only-child::after,
.tree li:only-child::before {
 display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child {
 padding-top: 0;
}

/*Remove left connector from first child and right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before,
.tree li:last-child::after {
 border: 0 none;
}

/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li:last-child::before {
 border-right: 0.3125em solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 0 0.3125em 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0 0.3125em 0 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 0 0.3125em 0 0;
}

.tree li.dotted:last-child::before {
 border-right: 0.1875em dotted #456990;
 border-radius: 0 0 0 0; 
 -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::after {
 border-radius: 0.3125em 0 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0.3125em 0 0 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 0.3125em 0 0 0;
}

/* no angle rounding for dotted lines in the exhusband/Woman class: */
.tree li.dotted:first-child::after {
 border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
}

/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/

.tree ul ul::before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 50%;
 width: 0;
 height: 1.3125em;
 /* 1.3125em = 21px */
}

.tree  ul.normal::before {
 border-left: 0.3125em solid #ccc;
}

.tree  ul.dotted::before { 
 border-left: 0.1875em dotted #456990;
 border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
}

.tree li .family {
 position: relative;
}

/* Person */
.person {
 border: 0.1875em solid black;
 padding: 0.09375em;
 /* 0.09375em = 1.5px */
 min-width: 18.75em;
 /* 18.75em = 300px; */
 /* min-height: 6.25em;  to increase the min height of the boxes */
 display: inline-block;
 /* preventing line breaks: */
 white-space: nowrap;
}

.person.female {  
 top: 0px; 
 border-color: #F45B69;
}

.person.male {
 top: 0px;
 border-color: #456990;
}

.person .content {
 position: relative;
 font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica", "sans-serif";
 font-size: 1em;
 align: center; 
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p align=center>
<br><br>
<b>
<font size=6> <I> FAMILY TREE </I> </font>
</br>

<div class="tree" align=center>
<ul class="normal">
<li>
    <div class="person child male">
        <div class="content">
            Maurice Dupont </br> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="normal">
        <li>
            <div class="person child male">
                <div class="content">Uncle</br></br></div>
            </div>              
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="person child female">
                <div class="content">Aunt</div>
            </div>              
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="person child female">
                <div class="content">Mother</br></div>
            </div>
            <ul class="dotted">
                <li class="dotted">
                    <div class="person child male">
                        <div class="content">Me</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class = "dotted">
                    <div class="person child female">
                        <div class="content">Sister</div>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="normal">
                        <li>
                            <div class="person child male">
                                <div class="content">Me</div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="person child female">
                                <div class="content">Other</div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>   
            </ul>                               
        </li>
    </ul>       
</li>
</ul>
</div>

</p>
```